# How can I get this ContextMenu control for WinForm?

Tags: winforms, controls, contextmenu, contextmenustrip

I want to implement ContextMenu like this in Visual Studio's dialog form

[image: Control Image Link]
<sub>(source: [devpia.com](http://pds.devpia.com/MAEUL/8/csharp_qa/154000/153309/%EB%AA%85%EB%A0%B9%20%EC%BB%A8%ED%8A%B8%EB%A1%A4.png))</sub>

Comment: Haven't you try to ask Mr.Google .. with 'contextmenu NET' ?  or something like that ?